# Dereference pointer variable to the same type without reference in Golang

Tags: pointers, go, reference

My application has a type Event:

```
type Event struct {
    Id string
}
```

Sometimes I have instance of this type with reference, sometimes without:

```
var event *Event
```

But function needs this type without pointer:

```
func ProcessEvent(event Event)
```

So I cannot use my pointer var with this function. Maybe there is a solution to convert *Event to Event? Or I need to refactor my code to have all without pointer?

I use this solution, but I don't like it, because I need to duplicate my code:

```
event2 := Event{
    Id: event.Id
}
```

Comment: "this type with reference", help yourself by stopping thinking-of/referring-to pointers as "references". Go does not have references or pass-by-reference at all. Some other languages (e.g. C++) have a special syntax and concept of a reference distinct from pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert from pointer you need to dereference pointer: `*event`

From http://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators:

> For an operand `x` of pointer type `*T`, the pointer indirection `*x` denotes the variable of type `T` pointed to by `x`. If `x` is `nil`, an attempt to evaluate `*x` will cause a run-time panic.